# Can't login to terminal i get the following ......... login: login: could not determine audit condition (process completed)

Tags: command-line, mac, ssd, installation, terminal

I was upgrading my HDD to SSD on my mid 2011 iMac 21.5 in 2.5 GHz intel 
core i5 running High Sierra 10.13.6 used **[superdooper](https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html)** to clone the original HDD to SSD then made another **[superdooper](https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html)** clone to a second SSD.

I then installed the SSD in the old HDD space reassembled and everything is working fabulous but both versions of my old HDD on the new SSD's  show the following:

> `login: login: could not determine audit condition (process completed)`

When trying to access terminal.

My only experience with terminal follows. I'm not tech-savvy.

I entered:

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off   (once to disable spotlight)
```

And I did run the following:

```
sudo mkdir -p /Users/Shared  (then)
sudo chown root:wheel /Users/Shared (then)
sudo chmod -R 1777 /Users/Shared
```

This was advised to me and quite frankly I don't recall why.

I'm of course on a steep learning curve here but can follow directions. Can anyone help? I cannot access the terminal at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well after a few hours of wasted research I then decided contacted support @ https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/13803/superduper I took Dave Nanians advise and reloaded my mac os 10.13.6 from online while i was on the same ssd as i was trying to secure my terminal access on and while it was downloading i patiently waited holding my breathe it took about 45 min but it came up to my login window i typed my password and lo and behold i have regular access to terminal everything is a ok did the same action to the other ssd and waalaw its also fully operational with terminal access  problem solved i hope this helps the rest of you who find yourselves stuck as i was CHEERS!